# Gronwall inequality for integrable functions

Tags: measure-theory, inequality, partial-differential-equations, lp-spaces, integral-inequality

In the book "Some Gronwall type inequalities and applications" (Theorem 5): Let $x:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function that satisfies the inequality
$$\frac{x^2(t)}{2} \leq \frac{x^2_0}{2}+\int_a^t \Psi (s)x(s) ds, \ t \in [a,b]$$
where $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\Psi$ are nonnegatives continous in $[a,b]$. Then the estimation
$$|x(t)|\leq |x_0|+\int_a^t\Psi(s)ds, \ t \in [a,b]$$
holds.
Can we to have the same result if replace "$x$ continuous" for "$x$ integrable" or $x \in L^2(0,\infty; \mathbb{R})$ (for example)? Im trying addapt the solution for $x$ integrable. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Go through the proof of Theorem 5. Where do they make use of the continuity of $x$? How can you adapt either the theorem or the proof to make continuity not necessary? At the very best, you will have to live with the inequality only holding almost everywhere.